# Under which condition should I choose the JDK provider and its pros and cons?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

May I know what are the JDK provider choices for Spring Boot if I am using Kotlin with Java 8 along with AWS EC2?

I saw many providers out there but I don't know which one I should use, based on what scenario and what are their pros and cons?

Comment: Amazon recommends the usage of Amazon Corretto, it's their own distribution of OpenJDK https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/what-is-corretto-8.html

I personally use https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot and never had any issues with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Many vendors

Several vendors provide binaries of the JDK, some with installers. These vendors include Azul Systems, IBM & Red Hat, SAP, Oracle, BellSoft, Pivotal, Adoptium, Amazon, Microsoft, and more.

Nearly all of them are based largely on the source code from the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project.

All of them have been thoroughly tested. All of them run Spring Boot.

There are no “bad” JDKs. Choose based on features, such as some use the HotSpot JIT while others use the OpenJ9 JIT. And choose based on support: some companies offer support plans for a fee. And choose based on license, be sure to read the details as the licenses do vary.

## Amazon *Corretto*

For use with Amazon Web Services (AWS), you may want to choose Amazon’s offering, [Corretto](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/?filtered-posts.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&filtered-posts.sort-order=desc). They promise that the Corretto releases are virtually identical to the implementation used by their AWS products.